# Pandas datetime conversion does not recognize my input

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-conversion

I have this big set of data where date and time have separate columns. I want to convert them to string and subsequently convert them to datetime time. However, this value error always pops up.

```
ValueError: time data '200101030' does not match format '%Y%m%d%H%M%S' (match)
```

Here is the data format:

```
 <DTYYYYMMDD>  <TIME>  Adj. Open  Adj. High  Adj. Low  Adj. Close  volume
   20010102  230100     0.5617     0.5617    0.5617      0.5617       4
   20010102  230400     0.5616     0.5616    0.5616      0.5616       4
```

Below is the code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('AUDUSD.txt')
df['DATE']=df['<DTYYYYMMDD>'].map(str)+df['<TIME>'].map(str)
df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
print(df.head(15))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem some bad data - in column `<TIME>` is `zero`.

Need parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert bad data to `NaT`:

```
print (df)
   <DTYYYYMMDD>  <TIME>  Adj. Open  Adj. High  Adj. Low  Adj. Close  volume
0      20010102  230100     0.5617     0.5617    0.5617      0.5617       4
1      20010103       0     0.5616     0.5616    0.5616      0.5616       4


df['DATE']=df['<DTYYYYMMDD>'].astype(str)+df['<TIME>'].astype(str)
df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S", errors='coerce')
print (df)
   <DTYYYYMMDD>  <TIME>  Adj. Open  Adj. High  Adj. Low  Adj. Close  volume  \
0      20010102  230100     0.5617     0.5617    0.5617      0.5617       4   
1      20010103       0     0.5616     0.5616    0.5616      0.5616       4   

                 DATE  
0 2001-01-02 23:01:00  
1                 NaT
```